# ext4-fs: bad geometry: block count exceeds size of device

Tags: mount, ext4, badblocks

I have 2TB disk that I use in notebook. This disk was formatted as ext4 and It works fine in notebook, but when I attach it to desktop (via sata-usb adapter), I am unable to mount it due to following error:

From desktop:

```
# mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
# dmesg | grep sdd
[ 6978.692452] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029166 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[ 6978.692604] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 6978.692606] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 6978.692799] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 6978.692803] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6978.789625]  sdd: sdd1
[ 6978.789631] sdd: p1 size 3907027120 extends beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
[ 6978.792344]  sdd: sdd1
[ 6978.792346] sdd: p1 size 3907027120 extends beyond EOD, truncated
[ 6978.793299] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[ 7002.085079] EXT4-fs (sdd1): bad geometry: block count 488378390 exceeds size of device (488378389 blocks)

# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398932992 bytes, 3907029166 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa3bf120c

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T 83 Linux
```

From Notebook:

```
# dmesg | grep sdb
[    6.747344] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    6.747347] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    6.747369] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    6.747372] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    6.747407] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    6.769650]  sdb: sdb1
[    6.770587] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   14.128886] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: data=ordered
here I tried remount it, and it worked fine:
[  286.189504] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa3bf120c

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T 83 Linux
```

My question is:
Why does one computer shows different amount of sectors on disk than the other one? I checked for bad blocks, none were found.

Comment: Buggy usb adapter with bigger sized hdd than it's designed.

Comment: @IporSircer There are something about adapters and disks sizes, but I cannot recall...it was mentioned here several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens with faulty USB interface adapters. Possible reasons for faulty adapters:

- Adapter too old
- Cheap adapter
- Bad adapter firmware

These errors became a lot more frequent with the advent of [advanced format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) drives.

Some adapters try to "translate" AF drive interactions so they emulate legacy format drives.

This means you can:

1. Use the USB adapter to format the drive, and then continue to use the USB adapter on both computers
2. Get a better USB adapter, so you won't have to format your drive.
3. Use internal SATA connectors on both computers.

**Formatting will destroy all data on the drive.**

Comment: Some USB bridges also support things like AES encryption, and reserve some sectors of the HDD for metadata. In that case it's a "feature" with side-effects. Same thing happens when moving disks to a RAID controller (single disk mode). Those controllers are neither faulty nor cheap, just made with a different purpose in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the reported sizes is very small, only 3907029166 vs. 3907029168, or 2 sectors = 1KB. You may be able to make this work by just shrinking the filesystem and partition on the laptop (where it reports the larger size) before moving it to the desktop system.

To start, you could just use `resize2fs` to shrink the filesystem by 1 block and that may be enough.

Depending on how the partition table is written, however, you may not be able to shrink the partition by such a small amount (e.g. it might need to be a whole track or 1MB or whatever). In that case, using something like `parted` that knows these details may be better.

As for why the USB adapter is reporting a different size, there are any number of valid reasons. Simple rounding or adding an internal disk label may be used by the adapter.